# MSVC 2019: Order of comma-separated conditions in C++ for-loop changes warnings

Tags: c++, loops, warnings, visual-c++-2019

Porting the below code to from VS2017 to 2019 popped up a new warning (this is a simplified version of the original).

> main.cpp(18,90): warning C4834: discarding return value of function
> with 'nodiscard' attribute

```
#include <map>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

typedef  map<int, vector<vector<void*> > > MyMap;

const int N = 16;

int main()
{

    MyMap myMap;

    for (auto mapIt = myMap.begin(), mapEnd = myMap.end(); mapIt != mapEnd; mapIt++)
    {
        int j = 0;
        for (auto keyIt = (*mapIt).second.begin(), keyEnd = (*mapIt).second.end(); keyIt != keyEnd, j < N; keyIt++, j++)
        {
            for (auto vecIt = (*keyIt).begin(), vecEnd = (*keyIt).end(); vecIt != vecEnd; vecIt++)
            {
                if (*vecIt)
                {

                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Note the for loop has two comma-separated initalizers, two comma-separated conditions, etc. If I remove the `j < N` condition from the for loop, the warning disappears. If I swap the two conditions, also no warning.

I assume the `!=` operator has some return value that is discarded and that if it is the only condition, or if it is the last condition it is not discarded? Is this expected behavior from the compiler ??

Comment: `keyIt != keyEnd, j < N` is only going to return the result of `j < N`.  If you want both conditions to be used, you need `keyIt != keyEnd && j < N`

Comment: ***two comma-separated conditions*** The first one will be ignored (well actually evaluated then discarded) by the use of the comma operator so its good that the compiler is issuing a warning of the non used condition.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other - read the section about the *comma operator*.

Comment: The difference is that the builtin comparison between primitives `j < N` is not `nodiscard`, and thus does not provide the opportunity for the compiler to warn you.

Comment: Were you intending to use `keyIt != keyEnd && j < N;` instead of `keyIt != keyEnd, j < N;`?

Comment: You can squelch the warning: `(void)(keyIt != keyEnd), j < N` ... that makes it clear that the first expression is intentionally being discarded.

Comment: It looks like VS 2019 correctly identified a bug in your code, where VS 2017 couldn't. If you say the result of `keyIt != keyEnd` isn't needed, then the test isn't needed at all. But from the looks of it, it's most probably needed. So: `keyIt != keyEnd && j < N`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all!
Seems indeed the intent of this legacy code was to `&&` the two conditions. The comma operator was a bug.